# XBee coordinator data package reception

Tags: data-structures, xbee, zigbee

Hi I'm creating a xbee network with 1 coordinator and 20 end nodes transmitting data 8 times per second. (Currently i just made one of them talk to the coordinator).

I would like to know how many data packages the coordinator will be able to receive as I'll be transmitting in a high data rate. (20 end index x 8 times per second its 160 data packages per second).

Is that feasible ? Will I face any problems ? What should I be worried with ? For that data rate is there any other protocol I could use?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would say that it isn't feasible.  The radio data rate of 802.15.4 networks is 250kbps.  Once you're sending that many data packets per second, you'll be getting collisions and retransmissions.  It might work if the packets are very small, but you'll still have a lot of overhead for packet headers.  If this is a mesh network, you'll be using bandwidth for packet retransmission when a node can't communicate directly with the coordinator.

Is there a reason you need that data frequency?  Can the end devices aggregate their data and send a single packet once/second with 8 data samples?  Zigbee and 802.15.4 were designed for low data rates and low power.

If you're going to try this out, you'll want to configure the coordinator for at least 230kbps to keep up with the data flow.  Do a proof of concept with a single end device (and configure it as a router, since you don't need "sleeping" capability of end devices), and then consider testing with 5 devices sending 4 times as much data (32 packets/second) to see if the coordinator can even keep up with that data flow.